# How to filter out values within a row and assign them to an array and find the minimum?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a different approach to a code I have been trying to finish for a week now.

My goal is to create a function whose input is a specific worksheet. I then want to find all the values in the 11th row of this worksheet that are between -100 and 100. I then want to assign these values to an array. Finally, I want the output of the function to be the minimum value between these numbers.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the code I have so far, however, it is only returning a value of 100 for some reason.

````
Function Loss(worksheet1 As Worksheet) As Double

Dim min As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim myRight As Long, Colcount As Long



min = 100

With worksheet1
    myRight = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Colcount = 4 To myRight

        If (.Cells(11, Colcount).Value < min) And (Abs(.Cells(11, Colcount).Value) <= 100) Then
            min = .Cells(11, Colcount).Value
        End If
    Next Colcount
End With


Loss = min

End Function```
````

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything.  How do you expect the value to be less than 100 and also greater than equal to 100 at the same time?

Comment: no, I want them to be greater than -100. How can I change my code to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the name of the worksheet, pass the whole range which you want to work on.

```
Option Explicit

Function Loss(sRng As Range)

Dim aCell As Range, minVal As Double,colNum as Long
minVal = 100
colNum = 0

For Each aCell In sRng

If IsNumeric(aCell.Value) Then
    If aCell.Value < minVal And Abs(aCell.Value) <= 100 Then 
        minVal = aCell.Value
        colNum = aCell.Column
    End if
End If

Next aCell

Loss = minVal

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: The OP clearly mention he is always getting 100, why is that because min value never changes

Comment: @johnny5 please be careful you are talking to Prison Mike, plus I have read the question and provided the answer and also test case.

Comment: Last question: do you think there is a way for me to assign the column number of the minimum value to a variable?

Comment: @YaraK yes. colNum = aCell.Column

Comment: @YaraK You're welcome. You can mark it as answer if it is answer to your question